# How can I change memory dedicated to Docker in Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, confluent-platform

I'm trying to run the confluent cp-demo docker image.

https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/tutorials/cp-demo/docs/index.html

I'm using Ubuntu 20-04 and in order to start the container I need to increase docker max memory setting from the default 2GB to 8GB.

This can be done easily on Windows and Mac by the Docker Desktop app but that isn't available on Ubuntu and I haven't found a way to modify it using the cli. (I can only modify the memory of a container after I started it with the cli,but in order to start cp-demo it says I need to change the memory setting first).

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, in mac and windows you can control memory and cpu for docker application but in Linux it directly usages linux namespaces and cgroups so you don't need to do any changes for daemon, docker will provide free resources available on host to containers.

For your requirements:.

> 1. Make sure host-machine have sufficient free resources available.
> 2. Start cp-demo with memory limit:.  docker run -it --memory=”2g” cp-demo